Why is my partition readonly flag being reset
I have a partition which I want to be readonly. It is one of several partitions on an external USB drive with GPT-style partitioning.
I have followed the instructions here and it works great for a while. In other words:
C:\Windows\system32>diskpart

Microsoft DiskPart version 10.0.19041.3636

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.
On computer: TURNIP

DISKPART> list volume

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 0     I                       DVD-ROM         0 B  No Media
  Volume 1         System Rese  NTFS   Partition    100 MB  Healthy
  Volume 2     E   Medium SSD   NTFS   Partition    465 GB  Healthy
  Volume 3                      NTFS   Partition    521 MB  Healthy    Hidden
  Volume 4     F   Small SSD    NTFS   Partition    111 GB  Healthy
  Volume 5     D   Magnetic di  NTFS   Partition    931 GB  Healthy
  Volume 6     C   Large SSD    NTFS   Partition   1862 GB  Healthy    Boot
  Volume 7                      FAT32  Partition    100 MB  Healthy    System
  Volume 8                      NTFS   Partition    554 MB  Healthy    Hidden
  Volume 9     G   Crucial X6   NTFS   Partition    476 GB  Healthy
  Volume 10    H   Crucial X6   NTFS   Partition    976 GB  Healthy

DISKPART> sel vol G

Volume 9 is the selected volume.

DISKPART> att vol set readonly

Volume attributes set successfully.


That works fine for a few days. But eventually I find that I can edit files on the partition again. Checking in diskpart, I can see the readonly attribute was cleared.
This doesn't seem to be caused by unplugging and replugging the USB drive, or by restarting the machine. The docs don't have much to say about it.
Why is the readonly flag being cleared on my partition against my will?

This seems to be a Windows issue; the OS is resetting that attribute. You can prove that by using the drive on a Linux machine for a while -- it likely will respect and keep that setting.

Do you know where the attribute is stored? Is it in the partition table or something?
